# Embarcadero C++ builder 10.4.2- Attach to Process not working on 64bit

Tags: c++, debugging, 64-bit, c++builder, 32bit-64bit

I used to work with C++ builder 10.1 (Embarcadero), with both 32-bit and 64-bit projects.
Now I am trying C++ builder 10.4.2.
Debugging 32-bit projects work fine, but on projects with 64-bit Target Platform the option “Attach to Process” is not working properly:
There are no red dots beside my code, and the process I was trying to attach my project to get stuck.
What can be the solution for it?

Comment: Make sure you have all of the available patches installed. The [10.4.3 patch](https://blogs.embarcadero.com/rad-studio-10-4-patch-3-is-out-vcl-grids-c-win64-debugging-and-c-android-exception-handling-and-resources/) fixes several issues related to the C++ 64bit debugger.

Comment: How can I install the patch? On the Welcome page, on the "IDE Patches" section it says "Your version is up to date", although my installed updates include only "Delphi 10.4 and C++ Builder 10.4 Update 2", and not update 3.
Can it be because I have a trial license?

Comment: did you read the install instructions on the blog article I linked to? "*Can it be because I have a trial license?*" - probably.

Answer (score 1):

It's apparently a known bug in C++Builder 10.4.2 that "attach to process" for 64-bit is broken:

[RSP-33839: attach to C++ 64bit process and debugging it does not work at all, 32 bit works more or less](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-33839)